# BufferedReader java not reaching end of file

Tags: java, file, buffer, bufferedreader

Currently I am trying to read a not so short stream from a response of content length 37743. I am using the read(char[] buffer, int offset, int length), yet not all the stream is being read when comparing it to the original json file I am reading. I've tried to check if this is a common issue but I cannot find any reasons why this can be the problem:

- max length of the String builder?
- max length of the char[] ?
- buffer length ? (currently 8192)
- incorrect while condition ? (following snippet)

```java
while ((reader.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1)
     sb.append(String.valueOf(buffer)); //sb is the String builder
```

Note when the buffer length is changed, the result changes again, e.g. when changed to 1024, the same result obtained with the 8192 buffer was achieved plus another piece of text which is not consistent with the original json string.

Comment: dont do String.valueOf(buffer) - StringBuilder has an append(char[]) method

Comment: Where do you get your `BufferedReader` from? Are you properly considering encoding?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should never ignore the result of `Reader.read()`. It returns -1 if the end of the stream is reached. If not, it returns the number of chars that have been read. Assuming that it reads exactly the number of chars you asked it to read is wrong.

Change it to

```
while ((read = reader.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
    sb.append(buffer, 0, read);
}
```

Comment: Or better, use one of the well-tested methods in Jakarta Commons [IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html)

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked perfectly. But it seams that your while condition remained the same as mine (except for assigning a value to 'read'). Does this mean that the problem lies in the use of the sb.append method?

Comment: Yes. Yours appends the whole content of the buffer, whereas mine only appends the chars that have actually been read: from 0 to `read`.

Answer (score 5):

You should write the sb object using:

```
public StringBuilder append(char[] str,
                        int offset,
                        int len)
```

with offset in 0 and len as the return value from reader.read

```
int len = 0;

while ((len = reader.read(buffer,0,buffer.length))!=-1) {
    sb.append(buffer,0,len);
}
```